# Connect to android device via WIFI

Tags: java, android, wifi

I'm trying to connect my pc to my android phone via WIFI..

But the problem is anytime I disconnect my phone from WIFI and turn it on again
I'm getting a different IP address so my pc doesn't connect until I change the IP address to connect to.. Is there any way to get the correct IP address of the phone?

Comment: Maybe having a file on a static address, which keeps the device's ip address might be useful. When you phone restarts, write the new address to that file, and have your PC periodically check any changes to the file. Just an idea. There are probably much better ways.

Comment: Isn't there a discovery library/protocol - regardless the IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be a router settings issue. Have you ever heard of "DHCP Reservation"? Most routers support such an option, which enables the router to memorize an IP to every distinct client ever connected and then to assign this ip to the respective client every time it reconnects.

Check your router settings / documentation for this option.

Here is a link, which could help you with your further investigation:

http://lifehacker.com/5822605/how-to-set-up-dhcp-reservations-so-you-never-have-to-check-an-ip-address-again

Comment: thanks, but wouldn't it be dangerous to have the same IP address for each device?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself a bit unclear. What I mean is: Every time a distinct client is connected to the router, it will always be assigned the same ip, which it has been assigned at the first time connecting to the router.